# Windows Network Authentication - Error 4625

Tags: windows, networking, security, iis, authentication

I'm running into an error when a particular Windows Domain is trying to access a website on my server - let's call it the ABC domain. According to users in this domain, the website prompts them to enter their Windows credentials. After 3 attempts, it brings them to a blank screen.

I've added the domain (ABC\Domain Users) to the Users group (under Edit Local Users and Groups in Windows) which should have access to the network according to the Group Policy. I've edited security permissions at the site level in IIS to give read permission to this domain group.

I'm relatively new to Windows Authentication, but I have searched and searched to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is the Event Viewer error details:

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          10/4/2016 11:01:56 AM
Event ID:      4625
Task Category: Logon
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Failure
User:          N/A
Computer:      tlcstdg47apdvg.adb.abcorp.com
Description:
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
Security ID:        NULL SID
Account Name:       -
Account Domain:     -
Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
Security ID:        NULL SID
Account Name:       A853965
Account Domain:     ABC

Failure Information:
Failure Reason:     An Error occured during Logon.
Status:         0xC0000413
Sub Status:     0x0

Process Information:
Caller Process ID:  0x0
Caller Process Name:    -

Network Information:
Workstation Name:   TUSFL000VM12492
Source Network Address: -
Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
Authentication Package: NTLM
Transited Services: -
Package Name (NTLM only):   -
Key Length:     0
```

Comment: Check if "Access this computer from the network" permission in Local security policy - Security settings - User rights assignment is granted to the connecting user. `0xC0000413` is a "This user has no rights to access this computer" error, meaning that it's authenticated against the domain, but is not allowed to login to this particular server. Also check if your site is limited to access only to local domain users and not say "Authenticated users".